# Can't implement RegEx on .dat file

Tags: java, regex, file

I have to read through a .dat file with restaurant names, addresses, ratings etc. and display anything that isn't formatted correctly. The problem is not with the regular expression.

My problem is that I have no idea how to implement the regular expression so that it can read through the files and pick out any errors in the formatting of the above categories.

The contents of the file are not evenly spaced out so I can't just make a constructor that reads each substring. Is there any way I can use regular expressions to pull out the information I need from the file?  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far.

Comment: sorry for not posting my code i wrote this from my phone but I just solved my problem thanks for the input though

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a regular expression, you can just test every line and print it, if it does *not* match.